# Verses related to Brahman?

Tags: mantras, brahman, stotra

what is biggest entity in hinduism, I thought its Brahman,
If it is, then please write, mantra, stotra, or any verses related to Brahman

Comment: your question is too broad. need to focus as there as thousands.

Answer (score 4):

Brahman is an ABSTRACT thing.

The Veda, Upanishads, etc, described Brahman in many ways.  Lengthy discourses were recorded on this subject.

[Mahavakyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81v%C4%81kyas) will describe in a nutshell about Brahman.

The Mahavakyas (sing.: mahāvākyam, महावाक्यम्; plural: mahāvākyāni, महावाक्यानि) are "The Great Sayings" of the Upanishads, as characterized by the Advaita school of Vedanta.

Most commonly, Mahavakyas are considered four in number.

```
Prajnanam Brahma (प्रज्ञानम् ब्रह्म)
Ayam Atma Brahma (अयम् आत्मा ब्रह्म)
Tat Tvam Asi (तत् त्वम् असि)
Aham Brahma Asmi (अहम् ब्रह्मास्मि)
```